# Page doesn't draw correctly on Safari browser

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, safari

The website (http://novascotiahomefinder.com/Annapolisvalley0416/) not redering correctly on Safari browser.

I think the
 ( `main .cd-main-content > div {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}` ) 
makes the trouble.

Please help.
Manoj

Comment: What do you mean by "not rendering correctly"? What is it showing vs what is it suppose to show?

Comment: not display properly.

Comment: Chrome and Firefox works well.

Comment: what about `overflow-y: scroll;` ? Works fine for me, I don't know what is the "right" result.

Comment: This might be a rare example of when you'll want to use a picture, as many members despise clicking random links with unknown intentions.